# Customise alphabetisation in index in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a document with a lot of proper names indexed. These include French style surnames such as "d'Albert". Is it possible to force Word to place this in the index as if it were Albert (i.e. between, say, Alan and Alcock), rather than under D?